# The difference between "on time" and "in time"

Tags: prepositions, time

I'm so confused while using "on time" and "in time" in sentences. 
I wanted to know if I have understood the meanings correctly.
Does "on time" means exactly at the specific time that was planned?
And does "in time" means sooner than the specific time that was planned?

So if your flight was at 3.00 and you arrived at 3.00 
You will say; I arrived on time.
And if you arrived at 2:55
You say; I arrived in time. 
Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: They're not really comparable. _On time_ is just an idiom that means 'punctual'. _In time_ is part of a construction with a complement; one is _in time **for**_ some event, like the departure of a train or the beginning of a parade. _In time_ by itself is just an idiom referring to rhythmic patterning: _His notes were not in time with the drumbeat_.

Comment: *In time* can also mean *eventually*.

Answer (score 1):

"On time" means that something happened by the scheduled time (whether earlier or exactly at the scheduled time).

"In time" means something happened early enough to allow for something.

One can obviously lead to the other, "my plane arrived on time, so I got home in time for the party". But one can fail to be "on time" while still being "in time" ("though the train wasn't on time and I was half and hour later than I wanted to be, I still arrived in time for the meeting").

("In time" can also mean "eventually" or with a rhythm and tempo matching the beat of some music or other frequency, but these are separate meanings).

Comment: +1 but maybe should clarify just hiw much early something can be and still be called “on time” and not early.